# android facebook login hashkey

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I need some clarification concerning the Facebook hash keys. Like, seemingly, everyone else I was having a problem generating a hash key until I found an answer on this site which I then used to generated the key:

keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\~.android\debug.keystore | "c:\androiddev\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "c:\androiddev\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64

It generated a key and I promptly updated the FB app (x0).

I start the app and try to log into FB and I get an error telling me no hash keys match t0 hash key go and configure your app. Basically, use the t0 hash key if you want to log in.

I have never seen the t0 hash key, have no idea where it came from or where it is stored. There is only one key in the debug.keystore from using the -list command which is the x0 hash.

**My questions are where did the t0 come from and where is it stored?**

Interesting thing is when I put the t0 hash into the FB app it runs like a champ.  I would post code but I have absolutely no idea where to start with this.

Additional info:

FB SDK ver 3.18

Built my login based on the Scrumptious Example provided by FB.

Using a Samsung Galaxy SIII for testing instead of an emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you set the Facebook App Id in your Android app properly?

Comment: Yes the app id is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It!

**DO NOT USE:**

https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/

**INSTEAD USE:**

https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

No idea what the problem is in version 0.98 but on a hunch I downloaded 1.01j just to see if there was a difference and it spit out the "t0" key. I hope that this solution will answer a lot of the hash key issues people are having because all the searching I did kept directing me back to the 0.98 openssl version.